# How can I remove and transform selective HTML tags?

Tags: html

I have a csv file of the format:

```
270291014011    ED HARDY - TRUE TO MY LOVE - Cap NEU 2008 NEU       0,00 €  0,00 €  0   1   0   22.10.2008 03:37:10 21.11.2008 02:37:10 21.11.2008 02:42:10 50  0   0   0   39,99 € http://i7.ebayimg.com/02/i/001/16/0d/68af_1.JPG?set_id=800005007    0   2   8.10.2008 13:40:20  8.10.2008 13:40:20  80587   0   <table bordercolordark="#999900" bordercolorlight="#666666" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="10" bordercolor="#666666" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><br>
</font></b><blockquote>
<div align="center"><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000">

</font></font></b><h1><font size="6"><b><font color="#990000" face="arial"><font color="#ff0000">100% ORGINAL MARKENWARE AUS DEN USA</font></font></b></font></h1>
<p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><font size="6"><b><font face="arial">ED HARDY</font></b></font></p><p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><b><font face="arial" size="5">CAP<br></font></b></p></div><div style="text-align: center;"><font size="5"><br><b><font color="#990000" face="arial"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial">Style: TRUE ROSE<br></font></b></font></font></b><b><font color="#990000" face="arial"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial"><br></font></b></font></font></b></font><font size="5"><b><font color="#990000" face="arial"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial">Die Kollektion von der trend Marke Ed Hardy kreiert sportlich, hipe Mode die bei den Stars in Hollywood der absolute Renner ist. In diesem super Trucker Cap fallen Sie auf !!&nbsp; </font></b></font></font></b></font><font size="5"><b><font color="#990000" face="arial"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial">Dieses Cap ist nagelneu mit Etikett und</font></b></font></font></b></font><font size="5"><b><font color="#990000" face="arial"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial"> 100% orginal.</font></b></font></font></b></font><font size="5"><br><b><font color="#990000" face="arial"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial"><br><br></font></b></font></font></b><br><b><font color="#990000" face="arial"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial">Wir tragen die ebay Kosten und der Kaeufer die Versandkosten.</font></b></font></font></b><br><b><font color="#990000" face="arial"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial">Versandkosten nach Europa sind folgend:</font></b></font></font></b><br><b><font color="#990000" face="arial"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial">fuer unversicherten Versand 6,00 Euro<br></font></b></font></font></b></font><font size="5"><b><font color="#990000" face="arial"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial">fuer versicherten Versand 12,00 Euro</font></b></font></font></b></font><br>
<font size="5"><span style="font-family: arial;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Bei paypal Bezahlungen akzeptieren wir nur noch versicherten Versand!</span></span></font><br><font size="5"><b><font color="#990000" face="arial"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial">Auf Ihren Wunsch versenden wir die Ware auch versichert. Ansonsten trägt das Risiko beim Versand der Käufer. </font></b></font></font></b><br><b><font color="#990000" face="arial"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial">Wir bitten um Ihre Zahlung innerhalb 10 Tage nach Auktionsende.</font></b></font></font></b><br></font></div><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><br>
</font></b></font></font></b><div align="center"><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="#ff0000">
</font></font></b></font></font></b><marquee width="70%" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<h2><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><b><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="#ff0000">Schauen Sie unbedingt bei unserem Shop "cheap-and-hip" vorbei!!!</font></font></b></font></font></b></h2></marquee><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><br><b><font color="black" face="arial" size="5"><br>
</font></b></font></font></font></b><blockquote>
<div align="center">
<center>
<h1><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><b><font color="black" face="arial" size="5">Abwicklung Ihres Einkaufs bei uns</font></b></font></font></font></b></h1><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><b><font color="black" face="arial" size="5"><br></font></b></font></font></font></b></center><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><br></font></font></font></b></div><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3">Jeder Käufer erhält innerhalb von 24 Stunden nach Auktionsende eine e-mail mit allen für die Kaufabwicklung relevanten Informationen. Sollten Sie nach 24 Stunden noch keine e-mail erhalten haben, setzen Sie sich bitte mit uns per e-mail in Verbindung. <br><br>
</font></font></font></font></b><h2><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3">Kauf von mehreren Artikeln</font></font></font></font></b></h2><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3">Da das Porto aus den USA nach Gewicht berechnet wird, werden die Versandkosten beim Einkauf von mehreren Artikeln neu berechnet. Bitte teilen Sie uns per e-mail mit, wenn Sie mehrere Artikel ersteigert/gekauft haben, bzw. noch ersteigern/kaufen moechten, Sie erhalten von uns dann die kompletten Versandkosten. Die Kosten fuer den Versand werden von dem Kaeufer getragen. Die Versanddauer betraegt bei Luftversand zirka 5-10 Tage.<br><br>
</font></font></font></font></b><h2><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3">Versand</font></font></font></font></b></h2><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3">Der Versand erfolgt innerhalb von 2-3 Werktagen nach Zahlungseingang (Gutschrift der Überweisung auf unserem Konto bei der Postbank oder bei paypal). Bitte beachten Sie, dass es je nach Kreditinstitut 2-4 Werktage dauern kann, bis Ihre Überweisung auf unserem Konto gutgeschrieben wird. Kreditkarten Gutbuchung ueber paypal erfolgt noch am gleichen Tag.<br>Als Betreff einer Ueberweisung muß unbedingt die eBay-Artikelnummer der Auktion angegeben werden. Ohne diese Information ist eine Zuordnung der Überweisung leider fast nicht möglich! <br>ZOLL: Bitte beachten Sie das Zollgebuehren anfallen koennen auch wenn es nur selten vorkommt sollten Sie sich mit den Einfuhrbestimmungen Ihres Landes vertraut machen. <br></font></font></font></font></b><br><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><br>
</font></font></font></font></b><h2><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3">Umtausch</font></font></font></font></b></h2><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3">Wir tauschen gerne Ihren Artikel um sofern Sie die Ware innerhalb von 14 Tagen nach erhalt den Artikel uns wieder zuschicken. Wir nehmen nur ungetragene Ware zurueck und alle Etiketten muessen noch an dem Artikel befestigt sein<br><br>
</font></font></font></font></b><h2><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3">Falls Sie Reklamationen haben</font></font></font></font></b></h2><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3">Wir bitten bei Beanstandungen der Ware sich erst mit uns in Verbindung zu setzten. Wir pruefen unsere Ware immer auf Defekte aber es kann vorkommen das uns etwas entgeht und bevor Sie eine "negative Bewertung" abgeben moechten wir die Chance bekommen Sie zufrieden zustellen. 
</font></font></font></font></b><p><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><b><font color="#ff0000" face="arial" size="5">
</font></b></font></font></font></font></b></p><center><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><b><font color="#ff0000" face="arial" size="5">Vielen Dank fuer Ihr Intresse!</font></b></font></font></font></font></b></center><p><b><font color="#990000" face="arial" size="5"><font color="#ff0000"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><font color="black" face="arial" size="3"><b><font color="#ff0000" face="arial" size="5"><br></font></b></font></font></font></font></b></p></blockquote></div></blockquote></td></tr></tbody></table><br><br>   1   Baltimore   1   0   1   0   0   0,10 €  0,00 €  0,00 €  0   0   1   77
```

I would like to know if there is an easy way with sed or awk to remove the HTML tags except for `<p>` tags. I would also like to know if it is possible for any link html embedding a Flash SWF file, to change the HTML automatically to link to this file.

So, in essence, to replace any code such as

```
<embed src="http://backend.supremeauction.com/app/gallery/loader.swf">
```

with something like

```
<a href="http://backend.supremeauction.com/app/gallery/loader.swf">Click here for external description</a>
```

and then remove all other HTML tags except for `<p>`

Is this even possible?

Comment: I am not clear what you mean here - the CSV file you have provided seems to have no HTML tags in it to remove? Also, you say "remove the html tags except for tags" - I think you need to format it as code.

Comment: Also, CSV to me means "comma-separated values", with one record on each line.  This looks more like HTML with some extra information at the front, but not a "true" CSV.

Comment: if you can first get the html out of the csv, and assuming the html is properly formed, it's pretty easy then to selectively remove tags using a dom parser, or even with perl-style regexps. post here if a regexp solution working directly with the html code would help you.

Comment: also, do you want to remove the attributes from the p tags too?

Comment: it is tab delimited instead of comma delimited. However the html will now be kept in, But I appreciate the responses.

Comment: kch has the right idea here -- a DOM parser will handle nontrivial cases in the parsing correctly, while a sed-based solution will just give wrong results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Perl for removing the non-p tags--it won't work across lines though

```
perl -pe 's/<\/?(?>[^p]|p\w+)[^>]*>//ig'
```

That will print it out to standard out and you can redirect it from there.

If you have only one link, you could do this:

```
perl -pe 's/<embed\s+src="(.*?\.swf)"\/?>/<a href="$1">Click here for external description<\/a>/i;s/<\/?(?>[^ap]|[ap]\w+)[^>]*>//ig'
```

Comment: beware that literal '>' is allowed within attribute values, so your regexp would fail for obscure-but-valid html.

Comment: I didn't know that was the case. Most of the time, I've gotten away with just that expression.

Comment: This is a pretty easy job for HTML::Parser, and that handles everything correctly. :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, for sed:

```
sed -e 's/[<][/][^Pp][^>]*[>]//g' -e 's/[<][^/Pp][^>]*[>]//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sf.net/) to filter out the tags you want; as it knows XML syntax (which is considerably more complex than can be correctly captured in a regex), it isn't prone to failure in corner cases like nested tags, and can decode `&amp;` and kin within elements correctly. The `select` subcommand will take XPath, so a trivial expression to find `A` elements will do what you want.

The `format` subcommand has an option to take HTML as input, so you'll want to do an initial processing stage with that if your content isn't valid XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in Perl, there are many HTML utility modules that can help you transform and filter HTML. Other languages probably have similar libraries. See, for instance, [HTML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Parser). You define handlers for the parts you want to affect. Once you get control of that part, you can transform it and decide how to output it.

You can probably get away with [HTML::Restrict](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Restrict), a specialized module based on HTML parser. You tell it which tags and attributes to keep and it gets ride of everything else:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use HTML::Restrict;

my %rules = ( p => [] ); # keep only <p>, no attributes
my $only_p = HTML::Restrict->new( rules => \%rules );

my $html = ...;

print $only_p->process( $html );
```

This won't work for your second question about rewriting `embed` tags. [HTML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Parser) can do that but it's more involved.

---

If you have very regular output that is generated by another program, you might be able to get away with a regex. However, whenever I've done that the regex starts to get pretty nasty as I find the special cases and exceptions.

It sounds like you may be able to turn this problem around though. Are you really just trying to extract URLs and link to them? Instead of messing with the parsers, can you just pull out the URLs and write a completely new document without caring about the old one? Or maybe just completely replace a region with the larger document?